# Two different Inheritance-chains without breaking the DRY-principle

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, abstract-class, dry

I have a problem with using the right inheritance-chain without loosing good parts of the DRY-principle.

Given the following structure:

- abstract class A is my base for all classes
- abstract class B : A is my base for all classes that can have special features (made available through B)

Now, I need to have two new classes which share the same features. But one is of type A whilst the other one is of type B. (This can not be changed!)
Both classes should have a method `SetSize()`.

So at the end there would be class C:A and D:B, both to have the same SetSize method.

Question: How would I create a base-class, intermediate layer to have the `SetSize()`-method only declared/implemented once (DRY)?
I guess something about using interfaces or some static helper-classes to implement the logic of `SetSize()`?

Are there any patterns or best-practices to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Related - [Prefer composition over inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Comment: Is the behavior of `SetSize` will be same for all implementations? (both for classes of type A and B, as you have mentioned `dry`)?

Comment: @Yogi The method will be exactly the same for both implementations. Thats why I'm looking for a way to have it  at one single point

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this via inheritance in C# because it doesn't support multiple inheritance; the tool the language gives you for this scenario is interfaces:

```
public interface  
{     
    void SetSize(Size size);
}

public SizableA: A, ISizable { ... }
public SizableB: B, ISizable { ... }
```

Also bear in mind that inheritance should be used when the types in the inheritance chain have a *is a* relationship (a `Cat` is an `Animal`, a `B` is an `A`, etc.) while interfaces are preferred when completely unrelated classes have a very specific common behavior; `IEquatable`, `IComparable`, `IDisposable`, etc. Your `SetSize` behavior seems to fit better in this last category as it doesn't seem to be a functionality specific to `A` or `B`.

Now, if both `SizableA` and `SizableB` should share the same implementation of `SetSize` then the best solution is to use composition or simply delegate functionality:

```
public interface ISizable
{
     void SetSize(Size size, ISetSizeProvider provider); //Alternatively inject provider in SizableA and SizableB's constructor to get composition.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an abstract class include SetSize() method and common properties of A and B classes.Then A and B classes inherit the abstract class.